# Why was the Israelite section in the Beis Hamikdash so small?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, men-male, architecture-design

The size of the Ezras Israel (where male Israelites are allowed) is 11 Ammos (cubits) long while the Ezras Nashim is so big (135x135 cubits).

Yet, it was the men who had to be Oleh Regel (when the "big crunch" was expected). Even if one says that there was a miracle, [it's not so clear](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%93_%D7%91) that we rely Lechatchila on such miracles.

Why (when they sanctified the Temple Mount) couldn't they have made the Ezras Yisrael larger (at the expense of the Ezras Nashim)?

---

**Beis Hamikdash floorplan:**
[image]

Comment: moreover, there were times they overflowed...I mean there were times there were 600,000 people there at a time, and another there were 1.2 million Pesach offerings (so at least 400,000 people at a time). That would leave everyone there about a square inch!!

Comment: tahts why the mishna in aboth says that when they performed heeshta7awoyoh in the beith hameeqdhosh, it was a nes since everyone fit without squeezing

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob heeshta7awoyoh was a nes. It doesn't say that standing was (they stood all around the Azara).

Comment: was just pointing it out that indeed the beith ha meeqdhosh was small

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob True, but I find it interesting how the Ezras Nashim takes up half of it (when they don't really have to be there so often).

Comment: just because they dont have to come Doesn't mean they don't. Plus there are more women then men for sure. If a guy has more then One wife that is a 1:2,1:3,1:4 ratio. You obviously need more room for the women up there than the men down there.

Comment: The *ezras nashim* was not just for women, and it was mainly used by men. See [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D_%28%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%29) and [here](http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5764/vayeitzei64/mikdash.htm).

Comment: Please [edit] in a credit for where you got this image from.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Don't remember from where I got it